# getting the 3rd slash using indexof

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a url `http://www.mysharepointsite.sharepoint.com/sites/test`.
is there any easier what to get the `/sites/test` than getting the 3rd slash and beyond?
and if not how can I get the position of the 3rd slash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use the .NET [System.Uri](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri(v=vs.110).aspx) Class:

```
([System.Uri]'http://www.mysharepointsite.sharepoint.com/sites/test').PathAndQuery
# Output: /sites/test
```

And here is a example using regex:

```
$site = 'http://www.mysharepointsite.sharepoint.com/sites/test'
$regex = '(?:\/\/).*?(\/.*)'

[regex]::Match($site, $regex).Groups[1].Value
# Output: /sites/test
```